# punto flotante a decimal en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, float

Buen dia

tengo este Query:

```
 $tabla_pc_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_WEBCT . "");
            while ($tabla_pc = tep_db_fetch_array($tabla_pc_query)) {
            tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set precio = '" . round($tabla_pc['CTPRC'],2) . "' * unidad");
```

donde CTPRC en un float y precio = decimal - con medidas 15,2

como hago para convertir el **float** en **decimal** antes de hacer la **multiplicación** que esta en el query? (la unidad es un numero entero no tengo problema, el float me arroja números como estos: 13.600000000000001 y solo necesito 2 decimales.)

Comment: ¿Has probado con `round($variable,2)`?

Comment: no funciona con round

Comment: ¿Dónde lo has puesto? ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para verlo?

Comment: editada ya lo coloque

Comment: Veo que lo estas haciendo en PHP utiliza `numer_format($tabla_pc['CTPRC'],2)` y te mostrara únicamente 2 decimales. Saludos.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function numer_format() in

Comment: perdon lo escribi mal es `number_format($tabla_pc['CTPRC'],2)`, las disculpas del caso.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Answer (score 0):

Podes *castear* en la misma consulta y alli utilizar la variable para realizar los calculos correspondiente.
Ej: `SELECT CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) - 2.0;` dara `-1.0`   [Puedes ver mas - Cast Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html)